# RegEx not validating decimal number without first zero

Tags: regex

I am using the below regex to validate integers and decimals in C# including thousand separators. This expression validates "0.5" but not ".5". Please suggest an edit to valid ".5" as well.

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]*)?$
```

Comment: Do you want to accept an empty string? `^(?!$)(?:[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?(?:\.[0-9]*)?$` or `^(?:[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*)?(?:\.[0-9]*)?$` will work, I think. Note the escaped `.`

Comment: No, empty string is not required

Comment: You mean "not valid"? So, `^(?!$)[+-]?[0-9]{0,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$` works, right?

Comment: .5 is now validated but 23521.21 and 1234 are not validated now. The expression i posted, it is validating 1234

Comment: Your original pattern did not pass them either. You need to match any numbers then with `^(?!$)[+-]?(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]*)?$`

Comment: Or use `^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$` https://regex101.com/r/vnCb3q/1 or `^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/LYdlV4/1

Comment: I tested this expression and it is fulfilling almost all situations:
^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
I am not able to select any that you have suggested. Please advice which to select that is more comprehensive? Commas (thousand separators) are optional

Comment: There is a little issue with the last two expressions you suggested. They are validating this 128,4,5.65 that is not right

Comment: Because thousand separators are not properly placed

Comment: You can use `{3}` instead of `{1,3}` like `^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$` https://regex101.com/r/76qWZ1/1

Answer (score -1):

The following RegEx covers almost all number validations:

`^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$`

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird for the suggestion

Comment: I just found out that the above expression fails for "9,999,999" value using Regex.IsMatch() method. Can anyone fix this issue?